# how to display options of select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display all options in my select tag when the user focus on the field or when my page is loaded:

here's my code

```
<select id='idSelect' autofocus>
     <option value='val1'>1</option>
     <option value='val2'>2</option>
     <option value='val1'>3</option>
</select>
```

I used the "autofocus" attribute but it does not work and then i tried to do in my javascript code like this

```
 document.getElementById('idSelect').autofocus = true;
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But it _does_ work with `autofocus` ... or you mean it should _open_ the select and show _all_ options?

Comment: yes i would like to open the select and display all options

Comment: using document.getElementById('idSelect').focus(); will focus on your select box but it does not mean it will expand the select box

Comment: Well, that is not possible

Comment: thx @khanShahrukh. is there any way to expand the select box automatically ?